# Error in Google Maps API V3

Tags: vb.net

I created an application program using vb.net and Google Maps API. When I run the program, the following error message appears

> You are using a browser that is not supported by the Google Maps JavaScript API. Consider changing your browser

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to define `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />` to see if it works,
or prevent error messages showing by using

```
<style>
    .infomsg {display:none;}
</style>
```

But you should know it will hide all kind of messages. There are also registry hacks etc. but not recommendable really, unless really needed.